# How to change texture on specific parts of 3D human model? (i.e., change the shirt using a 2D image of a shirt)

Tags: uv

I have 3D human models as rigged objects in Blender. I wish to change the clothing of these models using 2D images of clothes. For example, if I have a 2D image of a red shirt, I wish to project that to the front and back side of the 3D model to replace the current shirt the model is wearing (without affecting pants or head).

Any ideas for how to go about this? I am new to Blender. I have tried UV project and playing around with vertex groups (I have some body parts as vertex groups due to the rigging), to no avail.

Comment: To no avail... why? Show what you did, and how it fails... or why it is not satisfacting you.

Comment: My 3D models were 3d scanned, which makes it very difficult to UV unwrap since there are a ton of messy vertices. And I haven't been able to successfully project any image onto the 3d model.